# Exposure meter's result EV relative to the film ISO density threshold

Tags: film, exposure, iso, light-meter

Let's take a film with properly measured ISO speed. It means that there is some threshold exposure where it's resulting density (if developed to a specific standard gamma) raises just slightly (there is a standard number I don't recall) above the base fog. So the question is, if you take a reading of a properly calibrated exposure meter pointing to a grey card, at what distance it would be (expressed in EV stops) from that threshold?
My naive answer is
$$
\Delta EV = \log_{2}K = \log_{2}(12.5) \approx 3.64
$$
Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please define the type of exposure meter being used. Is it an incident light meter? A reflective light meter? If reflective, what angle does it measure?